# how to show display alert on xamarin with if radio button is selected

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

In my app, i have 2 options. Pickup and delivery. i am trying to show alert if delivery is selected and there is no address. I managed couple of conditions but couldn't implement the delivery radio button. at the moment, even i select pickup i get the alert. i just need to alert if delivery is selected.

```
private void PickupRadioButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PickupMode.IsChecked = true;
        DeliveryMode.IsChecked = false;
        delivery_pickup = "pickup";
        addressField.IsVisible = false;
    }
    private void DeliveryRadioButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PickupMode.IsChecked = false;
        DeliveryMode.IsChecked = true;
        delivery_pickup = "delivery";
        addressField.IsVisible = true;
    }

    private async void placeOrderTap_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((_cart.data.user_address == null && _address_id.ToString() == null) || _address_id.ToString() == "0")
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", Message.addressBlank, "Ok");
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it sorted..

```
                if ((DeliveryMode.IsChecked && _cart.data.user_address == null && _address_id.ToString() == null) || DeliveryMode.IsChecked && _address_id.ToString() == "0")
```

Comment: can do it in 2 days i guess. thats what it says